# Compare two columns for difference mark the difference in mysql

Tags: mysql, update, join

I need to compare two fields and mark the similar fields in third table.

For Example:

```
Tables

customer:
  phone id,
  phonenumber
  followstatus

received_Customer:
  rc_id,
  rc_phonenumber.
```

I need to mark the `fdnumber` with `f` or `n/a` in follow up which is in received and customer table.

```
update customer 
select b.phonenumber 
from received_customer n 
join customer b 
on b.phonenumber = n.phonenumber 
SET followUpStatus= 'y' ;
```

I run query in php.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct syntax for an UPDATE+JOIN. Try the following (assuming it is what you want, updating the table customer):

```
UPDATE customer b
JOIN received_customer n 
ON b.phonenumber = n.phonenumber 
SET b.followUpStatus= 'y' ;
```

Comment: Not Working .. ITs running on and on..

Comment: If you give us the structure of both tables I can help you with potential indexes to speed up the process like 1000x.